# Highlight A jQuery Radio Set among multiple

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, radio-button

Please refer to the sample code http://jsfiddle.net/ESDUD/

> **HTML**

```
<input type='text' id='abc'>
<br>
NIGHT <div id="radio">
    <input type='radio' name='myradio1' id='final' value='1'/>
    <label for="final" title='FINAL'>FINAL</label>

    <input type='radio' name='myradio1' id='maybe' value='2'/>
    <label for="maybe"  title='MAYBE'>MAYBE</label>

    <input type='radio' id='noways' name='myradio1' value='3' checked="checked" />
     <label for="noways"  title='NO WAYS'>No WAYS</label>
</div>
DAY <div id="radio2">
    <input type='radio' name='myradio2' id='final2' value='1' checked="checked" />
    <label for="final2" title='FINAL'>FINAL</label>

    <input type='radio' name='myradio2' id='maybe2' value='2'/>
    <label for="maybe2"  title='MAYBE'>MAYBE</label>

    <input type='radio' id='noways2' name='myradio2' value='3' />
     <label for="noways2"  title='NO WAYS'>No WAYS</label>
</div>
```

> **JS**

```
$("#radio").buttonset();
$("#radio2").buttonset();
```

Pretty simple....

But, When I enter some value in the first `textbox` and press enter a it shifts the focus to the radio sets, but the user is not able to understand that until the arrow keys are pressed and the select options change.

In order to change some CSS and highlight the the `radio set` in focus i tried the following CSS

```
#radio2 label:focus{

            color: red;
            border: 1px solid black;

        }
 #radio label:focus{

            color: red;
            border: 1px solid black;

        }
```

But, it has no effect.

My simple requirement is that when the `textbox` is blured I want some kind of highlighting or CSS change(even if its on the parent `DIV`) to be shown to the user so that the user can know currently the `radio set` is the active input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) on your CSS

```
#radio input:focus + label,
#radio2 input:focus + label {
    color: red;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Your current selector `#radio label:focus` selects all focused labels, which isn't what you're looking for.

[<kbd>jsFiddle Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/ESDUD/2/)